# changing a passed param from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing

I need to pass a param to a helper method, but it's not presenting as an integer. Why is my `param[:trait]` showing up as `{:value=>"1"}` instead of 1?  I am trying to pass it into a helper called `create_personality(trait)` and it won't accept `create_personality(params[:trait])`...but it works fine with `create_personality(1)`...if I just put the intended value in the brackets.

**cats_helper.rb**

```
module CatsHelper
  def personalities(trait)
    if trait == 1
     'Happy Cat'
    elsif trait == 2
      'Sad Cat'
    else
    end
  end

end
```

**pet.rb**

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CatsHelper

  def create_personality(trait)
    personality_kind = personalities(trait)
    PetTrait.create!(personality: personality_kind, pet_id: self.id )
  end

end
```

**pets_controller.rb**

```
class PetsController < DashboardController

  def create
    @new_pet = Pet.new(pet_params)
    trait =  params[:trait]
    puts "#{trait}" *1000 #This is how I know that {:value=>"1"} is being passed
    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_pet.save
        @new_pet.create_personality(trait)# <---- here is the call to the method
        format.html { redirect_to pet_path(@new_pet)}
        format.json {  render   }
      else
       # etc....
      end
    end
  end
end

_form.html.slim

      = simple_form_for [@new_pet], multipart: true do |f|
       = f.hidden_field :trait, value: 1
```

Comment: Since you use a `form`, the value should be wrapped into the `pet` resource. What value do you get if you call `params[:pet][:trait]`?

Comment: 0  ...trait is  not a column on pet

Comment: Have you ever inspected the HTML? I think it's a problem on the client side. If this site is online or open source than you can send me a link and I will inspect it.

Comment: It's neither, thank you though

Comment: I have quickly reproduced your scenario and it worked fine. Just take a look into the [Repo](https://github.com/tobiasfeistmantl/question-34109942) and tell me if something is different. I just used a quick scaffolding and installed `simple_form`.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you need integer value only then use `trait = params[:trait][:value].to_i`

Comment: That gives the error: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: The to_i needs to be in the call to the method...not after the params

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `f.hidden_field` is `simple_form` syntax. That's standard rails.

Try this:

```
f.input :trait, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 1 }
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the error, but thank you for the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

If `trait` is not a column on pet, you should try to use

```
= hidden_field_tag :trait, 1
```

Comment: that gives {:value=>1} for params[:trait] and does not pass if its' params[:pet][:trait]

Comment: Yes, and you should use `trait =  params[:trait][:value]` to get the parameter in your controller

Comment: This isn't the default behaviour of the `form helpers` so you shouldn't just use `params[:trait][:value]`.

Comment: @yang that gives me no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was a mix of two answers.  This is the working controller method...notice "to_i" needs to be IN the method call to work...AND it should be params[:pet][:trait].

```
 def create
    @new_pet = Pet.new(pet_params)
    trait =  params[:pet][:trait]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_pet.save
        @new_pet.create_personality(trait.to_i)# <---- here is the call to the method
        format.html { redirect_to pet_path(@new_pet)}
        format.json {  render   }
      else
       # etc....
      end
    end
  end
```